# Wordpress cannot make changes in my pages, update my plugins needs FTP credentials

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, sftp

As of today I cannot make changes in my pages, update my plugins anymore.

[image]

Since I only have a .pem file, I have followed this tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-password-login/

I created a password for the ubuntu user which is the admin.

I tried logging in using Filezilla and can access using this new password.

I can write into the:

```
var/www/jimclermonts/wp-content/plugins
```

[image]

Sometimes making changes in a page is not possible and another moment it works again.

Answer (score 0):

open your wp-config.php file and paste following code

`define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );`

inside it after `define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );` it will solve your problem.

example:

```
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

Comment: doesn't work. Should I restart something? And why do I have to add this all of a sudden it was working fine for the past months?

Comment: please check edited answer. there is minor change use define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' ); instead of define( 'FS-METHOD', 'direct' );

Comment: I've solved it. the problem was that last week the www-data user has been changed to ubuntu. Which means I could change files using Filezilla but not using Wordpress.  This has been changed back and ubuntu has been added to the list of users with admin rights.